# express.raw() doesn't inflate a zlib-compressed object

Tags: express, inflate, raw

Passing a uint8 array from browser to Node Express running in Linux container on Chromebook, to have content decompressed and returned to browser session.  The req.body initial bytes are x'68de' which are valid RFC1950 header data for DEFLATE. The returned req.body is the exact raw request image, not decompressed.

I was expecting an inflated Uint8Array of the input.